# Display views on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, views, mobile

As far as I can tell, currently there are no means to display the number of views of any given question on the mobile site.
All other relevant stats (number of votes and answers) are seen correctly, but it is impossible to see how many views a question has scored; to do that, one must revert to the full site, which isn't always handy, especially when accessing it i.e. from a smartphone or any other mobile device with a small screen.

Are there any reasons for this exclusion?

---

Here is the mockup; I've provided three possible places.

[image]

Comment: *> Are there any reasons for this exclusion?* – well, of all the information you might want from a question, this one's probably one of the least important. The mobile views are all about removing clutter, so it makes sense (to me, at least) to strip out that part.

Comment: This makes sense. I agree that in the question list more information could get it cluttered, but when opening a question itself, maybe some little space could be found somewhere to insert this?

Comment: Sure. I think the best would be to provide a mockup that shows where you'd want the views to be added.

Comment: Thank you, I'll provide it as soon as possible.

Comment: The mockup was just uploaded to the question

Comment: Any news about this?

Comment: Feature requests usually don't get this much attention on any Meta site other than [metase]. Which doesn't mean it's off topic here—quite the contrary, the communities are encouraged to post feature requests on their own Metas. Your idea isn't bad—I think you could squeeze that info in there—but it's just not that popular. FYI, [here's a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121974/display-view-counts-of-questions-in-mobile-version) on MSO which unfortunately got even less views than your question here.

Comment: Ok, it seems that not many people are after this feature; well, it would have been handy in some situations, but I can live with it after all.